# What do you use as a system to manage your clients/support/development?

Tags: project-management, crm, tool-rec

i am normally developing either alone or with 2-3 other people. i handle almost all aspects of the business and development but as of current i am becoming overwhelmed with my client base.  I need some system to help me out

What i am looking for is something that i can:

- Use to manage my client contacts
- Per client, manage the goals of the project im working/building on
- Per client, per project, manage the bugs
- Per client, per project manage support/helpdesk stuff... and then
  turn those into bugs
- Automate the communication of tickets and monitor email for support
  stuff.

I am down to hear ANY ideas/options you have no matter how radical. :)

thank you!

Comment: so far assistly.com is the closest thing i've been able to find.

Answer (score 2):

We have bought the Source Code licence to [JitBit Helpdesk](http://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk-software/), my colleague is in the process of adding some extra fields to support our work-flow, I have been working Visual Studio and AnkhSVN integration so that we can see bugs from VS2008/VS2010.

The user interface is functional, it can be styled to our likings, the code is a bit haphazard but the database is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) -- No complaints, and it covers just about everything -- and it's free to try.

Comment: Could you please tell me about it, what you like... what you dont like etc.  How do you use it?  Any info would be great.  Thanks for responding too!

Answer (score 0):

We use [HEAT](http://www.frontrange.com/heat.aspx) from FrontRange solutions for most of the things you've mentioned.  They also offer other solutions, such as CRM, etc.  Nicely customizable, easy to interface to, nice self-service modules, excellent monitoring tools and auto-escalations...  (and no I don't work for them.  I've just been very happy with them over the last 10 years.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Checkvist](http://checkvist.com) - it may work for you for clients/goals/plans/priorities. It is general purpose outliner and task manager.
For tickets/bugs you probably need a real issue tracker, like [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack).
Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) & [SimplyFi](http://www.geminiplatform.com/simplyfi)

Comment: If it's your own software you're suggesting, then you should mention that in your answer.

Comment: SimplyFi is our system, will remember to mention in future...